# Scan text from jtextfield for array

Tags: input, jtextfield

I'm trying to get input from a jtextfield into an array.
I'm using this line to get the text from the field but I don't know how to go about scanning this for an array.

```
double minutesIn = Double.parseDouble(minutesField.getText());
```